# get data from an api and store it in a state, but the state still shows undefined

Tags: reactjs

I want to get data from this api

```
export const searchSong = (songName) => {
axios.get(url)
  .then((data)=>{
    return (data.data.results);
  })
};
```

import `searchSong` in a component and run the function by passing a parameter and then store the data in a state variable like this

```
import { searchSong } from "../api";
    const songInput = async() => {
    setSongName(inputVar);
    let data = await searchSong(songName)
    setSearchedData(data);
  };
```

but it seems that this doesn't store the data in the state.
What am i doing wrong?

*I am a beginner to react, hope you will  understand*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`searchSong` simply isn't returning anything.  The call to `axios.get` is, but `searchSong` never returns that:

```
export const searchSong = (songName) => {
  return axios.get(url)
    .then((data) => {
      return (data.data.results);
    });
};
```

Which could be simplified to:

```
export const searchSong = (songName) => 
  axios.get(url).then(data => data.data.results);
```

(Which uses the implicit return of one-line arrow functions.)

Or:

```
export const searchSong = async (songName) => 
  (await axios.get(url)).data.results;
```

Comment: i just added a ```console.log(data)``` in the ```songInput``` function, and it actually sent request without running the above line ```setSongName(inputVar);``` and sends an undefines searchquery to the api. Ughh i think i need to start over.

Comment: @shoumiksk: *"without running the above line"* - No, it ran that line.  But state operations are asynchronous, so it sent the request before state was updated.  The value you want to use here is `inputVar`, not `songName`.

Comment: oh, so.. as state operaions are async how should i refactor it so that the state updates first and then it send the axios request?

Comment: @shoumiksk: You don't need to.  But if you really want to then you'd just perform the state operation here, and separately you could have a `useEffect` hook which monitors that state value and performs the search operation whenever the value changes.